# DevExpress MVC GridView: Colspan how to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

Can you tell me please how I can combine content of two columns into one, another words,
I need to render custom content for two columns but interpret it as a one column content.
After revising control and I think it equal colspan HTML.
Sample:

```
|--Col0--|--Col1--|--Col2---|
|--------|-CombindedContent-|
```

Using DevExpress MVC Griv View!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress MVC GridView does not allow for the organizing column in the required manner.
It is possible to use a merged column (band) at the first column level only:

http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/Bands

It is possible to use templates for organizing such a UI. However, in this case, you lose the built-in column resizing/best-fit functionality.